# How to get the order of each List item in Orchard Cms?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchardcms-1.9

I'm displaying a List of items in a widget container. This list have already been ordered using the dragable editor on the List container itself.

However, the Widget doesn't respect that order and have been trying to figure out the best way to do this. I'm getting the list inside the alternate shape template of the widget as

```
@{
IEnumerable<object> items = Model.ContentItems;
Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items");
Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("list-items");}

@Display(items)
```

I'll like to know the best way to get the order that is set on the list so I can manually controlling the rendering and use that order.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Can you specify what type of widget this is? You should in principle be able to use a projection widget, and order the query based on `Position`.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I just realised I got a response to this. It was a Container Widget